# Python global variable not working in recursive function

Tags: python, global-variables, quicksort

I wrote a quicksort program with Python and my goal here is to calculate total comparisons used. I declared a global variable named `thesum`. When I use `thesum` in the partition function, I can calculate the `thesum` correctly. However, when I tried to calculate the sum in the recursive function it gave wrong answers. Here are what I did respectively:

**Method 1:**

Calculate the sum in partition function:

```
def partition(listToSort, start, end):                                                                                                                 
    global thesum          
    thesum = thesum+end-start
```

In the partition algorithm I'm using, I need to add m-1 when partitioning a m-length array.

**Method 2:**

calculate the sum in the recursive function qsort:

```
def qsort(listTo, start, end):
    if start >= end :
        return                                                                                                                                         
    else:
        index = partition(listTo, start, end)
        qsort(listTo, start, index-1)
        global thesum
        thesum = thesum + index-1-start
        qsort(listTo, index+1, end)
        thesum = thesum + end-index-1
```

In this method, `thesum` is not initialized to `0` but the length of the original array minus 1.

**Things you may also need to know:**

The algorithm I'm implementing is a simple version of quicksort. I have a list and need to sort it with this program. I use a global variable to denote the total comparisons the algorithm need to perform.

**The problem and question**

I think the two methods are equivalent but they gave different answers. After some testing by printing `thesum`, I found that this global variable didn't work as expected in the function `qsort`. 
for example when sorting a 10-elements array, `thesum` was initialized to 9 but later printed out as 8, which is strange.
But why? I declare it as global in the function and it's used in the same way as in the function `partition`. All the difference I can think of is that `qsort` is a recursive function. But how does that make any difference? So global variables are not supposed to use in recursive functions?

Comment: For recursive calls, you'd probably be better off adding thesum as a parameter to the call.  It's probably not working because the value is not what you are expecting, when you are expecting it.

Comment: global and recursive should not be used in the same sentence

Comment: Shouldn't you update thesum (in Method #2) BEFORE your first call to qsort?

Answer (score 0):

The two methods are not performing equivalent operations.